# Copy files before compilation

Tags: qt, qmake

I've a master project with many sobprojects, that I compile using qmake.

In a sub-project I must copy some files **before** compilation (some header file). I've seen some command to perform operation before and after linking, but I'd like to know if it's possible to perform some shell operation before start compilation. I can't refer to them, but I must to copy them (don't ask why please, it's not my fault :-( ). Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do can be accomplished with careful use of the QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS and QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS variables.  The Qt Labs article [The Power of QMake](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2008/04/16/the-power-of-qmake/) gives a reasonable introduction to it.   The ".commands" part of the extra compiler can be any arbitrary command, including a shell command.

The other suggestion I found in this [e-mail exchange](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-11/thread00934-0.html) is to "... take a look at mkspecs/features/*.prf - especially those of moc and uic.." for other possible ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks I'll check your resources and I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 3):

see my last **answer** on nearly the same question:

> > **[Copy some file to the build directory after compiling project with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672130/)**

the only difference for you is to change in point 5:

```
POST_TARGETDEPS     += copyfiles ## copy files after source compilation
```

to:

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS     += copyfiles ## copy files before source compilation
```

when executing **qmake** there have to **exist** all **files** already in filesystem **before**

Answer (score 0):

I also just played around with `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS` to solve the question, but could not manage to get it done ;)

One other (simple) solution which might work for you is to wrap the call to `gcc`/`g++`: in the `.pro` file, set `QMAKE_CXX=./g++Wrapper` and in the `g++Wrapper` shell script, call the original compiler while doing anything you want before and after the call:

```
#!/bin/bash
DoWhateverYouWantBeforeCompilation
g++ $*
DoWhateverYouWantAfterCompilation
```

By evaluating the command line parameters, you could also restrict your actions to specific files.

Comment: I think something similar, too, but I'd like to perform operations from inside Qt Creator. I'll use this solution if I will not find any alternative. Thanks.