# Copy some file to the build directory after compiling project with Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

Done as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810877/630169 However make says me:

> make: Nothing to be done for `install'.

And nothing copied to build dir. Pro file contains following lines:

```
wav_files.path = %{buildDir}
wav_files.files += %{sourceDir}/hurray.wav

INSTALLS += wav_files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is what i am using for copying additional runtime files to build path and install destinitation:

1. define youre files here.

   ```
   ## === define copy files for installation and build ===

   copytarget.path    = /path/to/installation
   copytarget.files  += $$files(example/filename*)
   ## wildcard for filename1 filename2 filename3 ...

   message("found files for copytarget: "$$copytarget.files)
   ```
2. you must add a qmake compiler:

   ```
   ## === os specific dir separator ===

   win32: copytarget.files ~= s,/,\\,g


   ## === copy compiler for makefile ===

   DirSep = /
   win32: DirSep = \\

   for(f,copytarget.files) tmp += $$PWD$$DirSep$${f} ## make absolute paths
   copycompiler.input        = tmp

   isEmpty(DESTDIR):DESTDIR=.
   copycompiler.output       = $$DESTDIR$$DirSep${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}${QMAKE_FILE_EXT}

   copycompiler.commands     = $(COPY_FILE) ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}

   copycompiler.CONFIG       = no_link no_clean
   ## other CONFIG options are: depends explicit_dependencies target_predeps

   copycompiler.variable_out = QMAKE_DISTCLEAN
   QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += copycompiler
   ```
3. a separate makefile target:

   ```
   ## == makefile copy target ===
   copyfiles.recurse_target = compiler_copycompiler_make_all
   copyfiles.depends        = $$copyfiles.recurse_target
   copyfiles.CONFIG        += recursive
   ```
4. append the target after source build step:

   ```
   QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copyfiles
   POST_TARGETDEPS     += copyfiles ## copy files after source compilation
   ```
5. to include runtime files to install destination

   ```
   INSTALLS += copytarget
   ```

Comment: Thanks for You answer, will check when able.

Comment: Hi there, how could you adapt this solution to copy files that are generated by a target? For the example let's say I want to copy the dll file of a library target once it is built.